# Obter o conteúdo da última linha de um arquivo em Java

Tags: java, arquivo

Eu preciso recuperar de um arquivo sempre a última linha escrita. Sei que uma forma de fazer isso seria:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
public class LineReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LineNumberReader lineCounter = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\MyFile.txt")));
        String nextLine = null;
        try {
            while ((nextLine = lineCounter.readLine()) != null) {
                if (nextLine == null)
                    break;
                System.out.println(nextLine);
            }
            System.out.println("Total number of line in this file " + lineCounter.getLineNumber());
        } catch (Exception done) {
            done.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Mas existe algum método pronto em java para obter essa linha sem ter que percorrer todas as linhas do arquivo? Ainda mais que eu nunca vou saber quantas linhas ele já tem.

Answer (score 4):

Tente usar o método [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class LerArquivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(new File("C:\\MyFile.txt").toPath());
        System.out.println("Número de linhas: " + linhas.size());
        System.out.println("Última linha: " + linhas.get(linhas.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: E se o arquivo tiver uns 20GB?

Comment: @TomMelo Neste caso você provavelmente vai ter um `OutOfMemoryError`. Se não tiver, ele deve funcionar, mas vai entulhar a memória e dar muito trabalho para o coletor de lixo. No entanto, se você está tendo que ler arquivos de texto de 20 Gb sequencialmente, a sua abordagem ao problema claramente não é adequada.

Comment: Então, nesse caso, se eu tiver que ler a última linha de um arquivo de 20GB essa abordagem do Files.readAllLines não é adequada, correto?

Comment: @TomMelo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244450/132

Comment: Exato! Foi esse meu questionamento, uma solução que atende qualquer cenário. Acho que seria legal você editar e colocar a solução com RandomAccessFile.

Answer (score 2):

Já que você não sabe a quantidade de linhas nem o tamanho do arquivo: [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Você pode fazer sua própria implemetação ou usar a implementação do Apache Commons IO: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html

```
ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(new File("seu-arquivo.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(reader.readLine());
reader.close();
```

Comment: Certo, mas como eu importo essa API Apache Commons IO?

Comment: Ao invés de `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. Isso evita você ter que capturar o `UnsupportedCharsetException` que nunca vai ocorrer.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Boa! Vou editar.

Comment: @LucasPletsch você pode adicionar essa dependência no seu arquivo pom.xml: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5

Comment: @TomMelo, :O  Eu nunca fiz isso. Achei o tal arquivo pom.xml do Maven. Basta colar essa dependência em qualquer lugar do arquivo? Peguei um espaço em branco e colei ela assim:

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @TomMelo Mas e agora, na minha classe no Eclipse, onde eu estou codificando. Como eu sei o nome correto da biblioteca para fazer o "import" ?

Comment: @LucasPletsch import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader; Você pode usar o ctrl + shift + o para o eclipse importar pra você.

Comment: @LucasPletsch http://www.mauda.com.br/?p=1308

Comment: @TomMelo Ok, eu incluí a dependência lá no pom.xml, salvei, fechei e abri o Eclipse de novo, e fiz o import como vc falou. Porém, o Eclipse continua dizendo que "org.apache can not be resolved". Do "commons" em diante ele não d´marca como errado, só o "org.apache".

Comment: @LucasPletsch segue esse último link que te mandei primeiro. Cria o projeto maven e depois coloca a dependência no pom.xml.

Comment: @TomMelo Ok, vou tentar isso. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Na versão Java 7 o método Files.readAllLines(Path p, Charset cs) requer o atributo final para especificar o caractere que servirá de referência para a quebra de linha. Sugiro que acrescente:

```
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(
          new File("C:\\MyFile.txt").toPath(),     
          Charset.defaultCharset()
    );
```

Comment: Mas essa forma não retorna a última linha apenas. O que autor quer é retornar apenas a última.

Comment: Mas ele pode:  ultima = lines[lines.Count - 1]

Answer (score 0):

Para arquivos que sejam muito grandes (alguns gigabytes), a maior parte das abordagens seriam de ler ele sequencialmente, o que seria demasiadamente lento e poderia dar um `OutOfMemoryError` se o programa armazenasse tudo isso em memória.

Para solucionar esse problema, segue uma abordagem que lê o arquivo de trás para frente:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class LerArquivoDeTrasParaFrente {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("C:\\MyFile.txt");
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r")) {
            byte b = 0;
            long t = raf.length();
            for (long n = 0; t - n >= 0 && b != '\r' && b != '\n'; n++) {
                raf.seek(t - n);
                b = (byte) raf.read();
            }
            System.out.println("A última linha é: " + raf.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```